# Trading and Lego VIP

Tags: shopping, trading

What websites can be used for trading? I want to  have as many rare ones without buying anything. Does someone want to trade a Lego minifigure for free? I have been trying to get many Lego minifigures for a stop-motion movie.

Finally, how do I get all my free stuff from Lego VIP without buying anything?

Comment: hello! if  you have  been to the lego website, there is a new thing called lego vip. if you signed in your account and sign up for the vip there is some cool rewards about it.

Answer (score 3):

The go-to sites regarding LEGO brick trading are [bricklink.com](https://bricklink.com) and [brickowl.com](https://brickowl.com). They operate as marketplaces where people can buy and sell sets, parts and minifigs alike. There is one site I've found that is marketed as a dedicated place to trade (or in other words swap) minifigures: [swapfig.com](https://swapfig.com) - Note that there is not much experience with this platform, so exercise caution when operating there.

Regarding the "Finally" part: I don't know of any such opportunities, could you please clarify what have you heard/read and where?

---

Edit based on OP's comment:

LEGO VIP is not a new thing, but it is not about free stuff. You can register an account, and then collect VIP points with every purchase on LEGO.com. These points can then be exchanged for discounts or promotional sets. Sometimes minuscule amounts can be earned by other activities, like completing surveys.